# How can I reduce the padding on a Dialog?

Tags: codenameone

When I press a button, my app displays a calendar (within a Dialog) that slides from the bottom of the screen:

[image]

I want the Calendar to occupy the whole width of the screen, but it shows some white padding on both sides and also on the top and bottom (It is white because the "Dialog" UIID has a white created image as background)

[image]

I have tried changing all the UIID related to Dialog: "Dialog", "DialogBody", "DialogTitle", etc. I set all margins and paddings to cero.

**How can I get rid of that padding?**

Comment: Try "DialogContentPane" as well

Answer (score 1):

Try change both the DialogUIID and the UIID of the dialog. Also make sure your calendars margin values are set to zero. It could be that your calendar is too small. Try placing it in a table layout with 1 row and 1 column then in layout constraints set the width and height to 100%

Comment: All the Containers included in the Calendar have been set to 0 margin and 0 padding. What do you mean with "the UIID of the dialog"?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Component Inspector tool and traverse the hierarchy. You will be able to see all the components and their UIID's within the hierarchy and you should be able to understand which one of those components contributes to the padding/margin.